# Noun for both false positives and false negatives

Tags: single-word-requests

> Algorithm X was applied to the data. There were neither false positives nor false negatives.

I'd like to replace the second sentence with

> There were no _______.

Which word covers both *false positive* and *false negative* and fits a technical report?

Answer (score 2):

How about *there were no inaccurate results* or *no errors*?

Comment: Maybe; I was hoping for a more specific statistical term.

Comment: @Tim: 'error' is not an appropriate technical term?

Comment: @Tim Perhaps "There were no mis-classifications" or "Algorithm X was applied to the data and classified all the data correctly" might work for you depending on what Algorithm X actually does.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the *[Type I and II errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_I_and_type_II_errors)* Wikipedia article,

> Type I error ... and Type II error ... are precise technical terms used by statisticians to describe particular flaws in a testing process, where ... something that should have been accepted was rejected, and where something that should have been rejected was accepted (respectively).
>   Unfortunately, the terms are also used, in a far more general way, by social scientists and others ...

I think one can draw two conclusions from this:

1. One can reasonably say "There were no Type I or II errors" when one means "There were neither false positives nor false negatives."
2. It's unlikely, because of the mentioned misuse of statistical terms, that shorter precise phrasing exists; and if your testing does not conform to usual [hypothesis testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothesis_testing) convention, do not use *Type I* and *II* terminology.

Answer (score 1):

How about *there were no false positives nor negatives*? It's not a single word, but it may make the original sentence more fluent.

Or maybe the simpler *there were no false results*? Considering that the audience has some knowledge that would let them infer that by *false result* you are meaning both *false positives* and *false negatives*.

Comment: "There were no false results" has merit, but "there were no false positives nor negatives" has a problem; it is ambiguous or a double negative.  One could  grammatically but clumsily say "there were neither false positives nor negatives".

Answer (score 0):

*[Spurious](http://vocabulary-vocabulary.com/dictionary/spurious.php)* covers both false positives and false negatives. Per the reference in the link:

> *Spurious* refers to things that are not what they are claimed to be.

The noun form of *spurious* (an adjective) is *spuriousness*.

Note also that *spurious* sees common usage in statistics, such as in *[spurious correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_relationship)*.

Answer (score 0):

"While there were errors in processing preventing three items from being handled, there were no misclassifications." or "... handled, no entries were misclassified."

> https://www.thefreedictionary.com/misclassifications
>
> tr.v. mis·clas·si·fied, mis·clas·si·fy·ing, mis·clas·si·fies
>   To classify incorrectly.

Perhaps more precisely, but less naturally "mischaracterise"